# Accessing a List within an ArrayList C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access a List within an ArrayList to bind that list to a listbox.

Here is the code for my driver class.

```
public class Driver
{
    private string name;
    private string occupation;
    private DateTime dateOfBirth;
    private List<DateTime> dateOfClaim;

    public Driver(string name, string occupation, DateTime dateOfBirth, List<DateTime> dateOfClaim)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.occupation = occupation;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.dateOfClaim = new List<DateTime>();
    }

    public string driverName
    {
        get{ return name; }
        set{ name = value; }
    }

    public string driverOccupation
    {
        get { return occupation; }
        set { occupation = value; }
    }

    public DateTime driverDateOfBirth
    {
        get { return dateOfBirth; }
        set { dateOfBirth = value; }
    }

    public List<DateTime> driverDateOfClaim
    {
        get { return dateOfClaim; }
        set { dateOfClaim = value; }
    }
}
```

I have a button which allows you to add a date for a claim to a driver, up to a maximum of 5 claims so I have a temporary list which holds the dates list before it is assigned to the list in the arraylist as the new driver has not yet been created in the arraylist.

Here are parts of the code from a form which declares and populates the arraylist.

```
private ArrayList drivers = new ArrayList();
private List<DateTime> claimDates = new List<DateTime>();

if (noOfClaims <= 4)
{
    claimDates.Add(dtpAddClaim.Value.Date);
    noOfClaims++;
}

if (noOfDrivers <= 4)
{
    drivers.Add(new Driver(txtName.Text, txtOccupation.Text, dtpDOB.Value.Date, claimDates));
    noOfDrivers++;
}
```

So my problem comes when trying to access the dateOfClaim list.

I'm trying to bind that list to a listbox and have tried using this to do that but am getting an error saying 'ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'driverDateOfClaim'.

```
lbxClaimDates.DataSource = drivers.driverDateOfClaim;
```

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `drivers` contains a *list* of drivers, not a *single* driver. Which elements date of claims are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: Why don't you use a `List<Driver>` instead of an `ArrayList`?

Comment: I've tried using both, having the same problems with either.

Comment: There are two things out there only for backwards compatibility - collection and arraylist. for new dev you shouldn't use them

Answer (score 1):

You need to index the array list.  You would need to access an item of the array list and then acces driverDateOfClaim for a specific Driver instance in the ArrayList

```
lbxClaimDates.DataSource = ((Driver) drivers[0]).driverDateOfClaim
```

Also in Drivers constructor you arent assigning the dateOfClaim parameter to the DateOfClaim property.

Comment: "driverDateOfClaim" is a List<DateTime>.

Comment: Yes but the binding needs to be done to a specific element of the arraylist in order to access driverDateOfClaim property within the Driver instance

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but am still getting the "'object' does not contain a definition for 'driverDateOfClaim'" error. I also fixed the driver constructor, not sure why I had it like that.

Comment: I think that might be because ArrayList holds a list of Object types. so you need to cast it to a Driver First. Ill edit my post with a cast.

I have used the 0th index as an exmaple but you would have to get the right driver from the the ArrayList you need

Comment: With the updated cast I'm no longer getting an error, but the listbox isn't displaying anything. Is there something I'm missing when it comes to displaying items in a listbox?

Comment: I would probably use the debug tools to check if there is actually any data in the list you are trying to bind.